# If I drop my heroku table, can I later restore the database with a Heroku backup?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-api

I'm having some issue with my migrations in Heroku. I've tried several things but none seem to work.
I feel like I should just drop the table that's causing the issue, which will delete all the data in production.

If I drop the table, and re-created the table, will I be able to restore all of the data I lost? Because I will backup my database on Heroku before I drop the table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should run a backup with

```
pg_dump -h hostname -p 5432 -U username -F c -t mytable -f dumpfile mydatabase
```

Then, after you have dropped and re-created the table, you can restore the data with

```
pg_restore -h hostname -p 5432 -U username -a -d mydatabase dumpfile
```

However, this will not work if the table structure has changed.

In that case, you might want to use `COPY` directly to write the data to a file and restore them from there.

Let's for example assume you plan to add another column. Then you could dump with

```
COPY (SELECT *, NULL FROM mytable) TO '/file/on/dbserver';
```

After the table was created with the new column, you can

```
COPY mytable FROM '/file/on/dbserver';
```

The new column will be filled with the NULL values.

Modify this basic recipe for more fancy requirements.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, Thanks for the answer. I will backup my production database on Heroku. Do you know if I will be able to restore the Heroku database if I delete the table and create exactly the same one again?

Comment: No idea about Heroku's services, perhaps someone else can fill in. But my answer should work with hosted databases just as well as with others.

Comment: Databases aren't directly hosted on a Heroku dyno. Furthermore you can pick your own database server and reference that server in your code/environment variables. [Heroku has a tutorial for their Postgres add-on](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups).